# get more details from bad_alloc?

Tags: c++, exception, memory, vector, stl

since vector gets long unsigned int call to `f(-1)` throws `bad_alloc`. I suspect a call is made with 2147483648, actually 18446744073709551615 since it is x64 system. How can I get information about details of the error? This may be generalized, how can I get more details than `e.what()`?

```
void f(int i){
    vector<int> v(i);
    printf("vector size: %d", v.size());
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    //f(1); // vector size: 1
    try{
    f(-1); // terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
           //what():  std::bad_alloc
    }catch(std::bad_alloc& e){
        printf("tried to allocate: %d bytes in vector constructor", e.?);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What sort of additional information are you wanting to see?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, the vector constructor you are invoking takes a `size_t` parameter, while you're passing an `int`. Crank up the warning level and your compiler will warn you about these things.

Comment: yes, it is true, I know, this was just brief test, important thing being what will I get when -1 is passed

Comment: Operator new is usually implemented using malloc() and malloc does not give any extra information.  You might try looking at errno if malloc failed because an OS call failed.

Comment: errno has only int set, no details, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as the standard is concerned, there is no extra information other than what is provided by `what()` (whose content, by the way, is left to the implementation).

What you may do is to provide to `vector` your own allocator, that throws a class derived from `bad_alloc` but that also specifies the information you want to retrieve when catching it (e.g. the amount of memory required).

Comment: if standard is not concerned, :p, any idea how can I retrieve what was -1 turn into in vector constructor?

Comment: If the point is just to understand what did the `-1` turn into, you can just do `std::cerr<<std::vector<int>::size_type(-1);`

Comment: I did and got: 18446744073709551615

Comment: @restart.localhost.localdomain: which tells me that you are running on a 64 bit system. `-1` in 2's complement arithmetic is "all bits on", and in the conversion to `std::vector<int>::size_type` (which is an unsigned type) it gets converted to the corresponding "all bits on" value (notice that this conversion is implementation-defined). This, for 64 bit types, is 18446744073709551615 (i.e. 2^64-1).

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
std::vector<T> make_vector(typename std::vector<T>::size_type size, const T init = T()) {
    try {
        return std::vector<T>(size, init);
    }
    catch (const std::bad_alloc) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to allocate: " << size << std::endl;
        throw;
    }
}

int main()
{
    make_vector<int>(std::size_t(-1));
    return 0;
}
```

A reserve instead of initialization might suit better.
Please have copy elision/return value optimization and move in mind.

Comment: isn't this just extended version of std::cerr<<std::vector<int>::size_type(-1); ?  nevertheless this also answers my question, thanks

Comment: I don't get your question. Feel free to replace the cerr and throw lines with whatever you want, throwing custom_bad_alloc maybe.